# return 0 if null count

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

source: has_many comments

comments: has_many training_comments

```
@negative_comments = Source.joins(:comments => [:training_comments]).where("training_comments.category_id = ? and comments.spam = ?", 2, false).select("sources.*, count(comments.id) as ncount").group("comments.source_id")
```

I want to list sources with their negative comments count but i am loosing sources which don't have negative_comments(training_entries.category_id = 2). I tried everything to achieve this. I tried left join, i tried ifnull but none of them worked. Any help will be really really appreciated..

What i'm trying to do

> **Sources        Count**
>
> source1          5
>
> source2          0
>
> source3          13

what i'm getting is

> **Sources        Count**
>
> source1          5
>
> source3          13

**Sources table**

```
id: integer
name: string
```

**Comments table**

```
id: integer
source_id: integer
spam: boolean
```

**Training_comments table**

```
id: integer
comment_id: integer
category_id: integer
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know about your database structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a zero because the standard JOIN doesn't produce anything when there is no match. You need to get a [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) past ActiveRecord; something like this:

```
joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON comments.source_id = sources.id')
```

AFAIK, you have to drop down to SQL to get a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Is there a way to join 3 tables

Comment: @rOrman: You could add another `joins` call (`.joins(:third_table)`) or add more SQL to the above `joins` call (`.joins('LEFT OUTER ... JOIN third_table ON ...')`).

Comment: @rOrman: What SQL ends up being used? You should be able to pull it out of your logs.